# Remove letters in word within pandas column if the word follows specific pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have used an API to download info related to companies and topics. Unfortunately, some of the topic/company names were downloaded with the letter b at the start and at the end. I do not want to replace them one by one and I am looking for a regular expression that can help me identify all the substrings that start and end with 'b' and remove the 'b'.

```py
news = {'Text':['bNikeb invests in shoes', 'bAdidasb invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian']}
news_df = pd.DataFrame(news)


outcome = {'Text':['Nike invests in shoes', 'Adidas invests in t-shirts', 'dog drank water'], 'Source':['NYT', 'WP', 'Guardian']}
outcome_df = pd.DataFrame(news)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about try this pattern

```
news_df.Text.str.replace(r'\bb(\w+)b\b', r'\1')

Out[1054]:
0         Nike invests in shoes
1    Adidas invests in t-shirts
2               dog drank water
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yeah, that is what I understand from his sample. Perhap, I should add beginning string anchor to replace on only `first word`.

Comment: No, I never mentioned where word needs to be in the string, @Andy L, your answer is correct and it is exactly what I needed! Thanks again!

Comment: @FilippoSebastio: oh, that's great. No need to do anything else :)